# Kafka use case to replace control M jobs

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, confluent-platform

I have few control M jobs running in production..
first job - to load csv file records and insert to database staging table
Second job - to perform data encrichment for each records in staging table
Third job - to read data from staging table and insert to another table..

Currently we use apache camel to do this.

We have bough confluent kafka license so we want to use kafka..

Design proposal

1. Create csv kafka source connector to read data from csv and insert to kafka input topic
2. Create spring cloud kafka stream binder application to read data from input topic, enrich the data and push to output topic
3. To have kafka sink connector to push data from output topic to database

Problem now in steps two we need to have database connection to enrich the data and when watch video in youtube it said spring cloud kafka stream binder should not have database connection.. so how i should design my flow? What spring technology i should use?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing preventing you from having a database connection, but if you read the database table into a Kafka stream/table then you can join and enrich data using Kafka Streams joins rather than remote database calls